# Perform regular expression on list containing multiple lines of strings

Tags: python

I need to perform regular expression to clean up the strings in the list below.

```
X = [ "This is a # scary wolf! ",
    "welcome to a mysterious  jungle",
    "2020 was the year to remember forever_never",
    "Remember the name s - John",
    "I      admire      you" ]
```

I feel comfortable performing the regular expressions themselves on strings alone, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle this example as they're placed in a list.

The output is supposed to look like this:

```
This is scary wolf 
welcome to mysterious jungle
was the year to remember forever
Remember the name John
I admire you
```

What would be the best approach to tackling this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "perform regular expression"? `re.sub()` or `re.search()`?

Comment: But whatever you mean, you can simply loop over all the list elements, and perform the normal string operation on it. You can use a list comprehension to make a list of the results.

Comment: I'm thinking re.sub to remove unwanted characters and white spaces

Comment: Also, what are the cleanup rules here?

Comment: So use a list comprehension: `[re.sub(..., item) for item in X]`

Comment: If you're a python programmer, list comprehensions should be in your basic toolkit.

Comment: What is the type of the output you want?? If you want a string output then just do re.sub(..., "\n".join(X))

Comment: Too many edge cases here ... please state clear rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel comfortable handling the individual strings, then you could write a function that takes an individual string in and returns it cleaned.

```
def your_regex_function(one_string):
    your code here that applies regular expressions to one_string
    return cleaned_string
```

Then you need to make a new list of strings using that function, which you can do with a list comprehension:

```
cleaned_string = [your_regex_function(element) for element in X]
```

The list comprehension will cycle through each element of X, run it through the function, and put the cleaned individual string as a new element into a new list.

Comment: This worked, thank you everyone so much for the help!